Smooth (locally trivial) fibration and submanifold
Let $f:M\to N$ be a smooth locally trivial fibration between smooth manifolds
and $L \subseteq M$ a closed submanifold of codimension $\geq 1$ such that $f|_L:L \to N$ is submersive.
Then, is $f|_{M\setminus L}:M \setminus L \to N$ a (locally trivial) fibration as well?

Let f:R^2 → R be the projection on the first factor and let L be the closed submanifold given by {(x,y)| x>0,xy=1 } union {(x,y)| y=-1 } . I think this is a counterexample.

Yes, it is. Thanks! What if $L$ is connected? Probably there is still a similar counterexample but I do not see it right away.
